How to escape the type casting in a function that finds its types based on the parameters of mapped functions?
I am having an issue creating a dynamic type safe function, it is shaped like the code below.
A wrapper function (testWrapper) takes an object that looks like
{
type: enum.enumString,
value: string || number
}

The idea is that the wrapper function receives the object then finds the mapped function and calls it, while finding the type based on the parameters of the mapped function.

//Enum 

enum FunctionNames {
printNumber: "printNumber",
printString: "printString"
}

// Mapping object
   const testing = {
        [FunctionNames.printNumber]: (number: number) => {
            console.log(number);
        },
        [FunctionNames.printString]: (string: string) => {
            console.log(string);
        },
    };

//Value type found based on Parameters

    type UpdateValue<T extends keyof typeof testing> = Parameters<typeof testing[T]>;


// Wrapper function
    const testWrapper = <T extends keyof typeof testing>(value: { type: T; value: UpdateValue<T>[0] }) => {
        const x = testing[value.type];

// Error on this line
        x(value.value);
    };


Our problem is that the  x(value.value returns a type error of:
Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

So far the only way to get rid of the error is to cast the type as never but I don't want to do that as it feels like that is not actually type safe.
How do we escape having to type cast the value.value?

What is enum.enumString? (and I think you meant value: string | number - not ||?)

@Dai its an enum used as the key in the mapping object, its passed to the wrapper function so it can find the appropriate function to call

Can you please include all the referenced types and values into your post so we can copy+paste it into TS Playground?

Done, also changed where its used

there's no link to the playground...

Please [edit] to make your code a [mre] that, when we copy and paste it into our own IDEs, demonstrates what you're talking about without having unrelated problems. That enum you added is syntactically invalid; please check your example code in an IDE before you post it so that nobody else has to debug stuff you're not asking about.

This is effectively ms/TS#30581 and the recommended approach is ms/TS#47109 as shown in this playground link. I'll find a suitable duplicate.
